# matrix downsampling C

Tags: c, image-processing, resampling

I have a **1280x720 buffered matrix** and i would like to implement a downsampling method which take one sample each 9 in both directions.

For example:

122222221222222212222222122222221222222221222222221.......

111111.....

so i implement this method:

```
int16_t* resample(int16_t *in_b){
    int scale=9,W=1280,H=720;
    int w=W/scale;
    int h=H/scale;
    int16_t *out_b=(int16_t*)malloc(w*h*sizeof(int16_t));
    for (i=0;i<h;i++){
        for (j=0;j<w;j++){
            out_b[i*w+j]=in_b[(i*W*scale)+(j*scale)];
        }
    }
    return out_b;
}
```

but if i draw an heatmap of the output it shows that input is repeated twice, what i'm wrong?

Comment: I don’t think you’re doing anything wrong.

Comment: ...not in the code you exposed. (At least, I cannot see something wrong.) May be, the error happens anywhere else or it's the correct result you just didn't expect.